# How to find a file and open it afterwards?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I want to create a batch file to search and open a file saved as a PDF. Should be simple. The files all have unique numbers 0-6000.

This is what I have:

```
@echo off
set /p current="ENTER GRN NUMBER "
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo Finding Certificate.......

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS\%current::=-%.pdf" 2^>nul') do set MyVariable=%%F
```

The files to search are all in `G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS\` & "several sub folders"

e.g.

```
G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS\1000-2000\
G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS\2000-3000\
G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS\3000-4000\
```

All the files are PDF's

I have tried the `dir` command but I must have git it wrong:

```
@echo off
set /p current="ENTER GRN NUMBER "
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo Finding Certificate.......

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS\%current::=-%.pdf" 2^>nul') do set MyVariable=%%F
```

Nothing happens

Comment: you already found it (or to be precise, the last of them, if there are several matches). It's in the variable `%MyVariable%`. To open it in the default program for PDF files (if there is one defined), execute it just with `%MyVariable%`. If you want to open it with a defined program, execute the program with a parameter (like for example: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "%MyVariable%"`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already set your working directory to your required folder: "G:\EMAX DOCUMENTS\MATERIAL CERTS\GRN NUMBERS", to find the .pdf file with your provided search key: `dir /a-d /b /s "%cd%\*\%current::=-%.pdf"`.

If you want to save that path to the variable: `for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%cd%\*\%current::=-%.pdf" 2^>nul') do (set MyVariable=%%F)`. Note that this does **NOT** show all results if there are more than one.

For suggested to open directly, assuming you have already associated .pdf files to a corresponding program: `for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%cd%\*\%current::=-%.pdf" 2^>nul') do ("%%F")`